# Extract a Node from XML based on KeyWord

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, xpath

The goal of my question is to take the URL of XML file and a Keyword (Name of a Node) from the user through a aspx Page.

1. If node has a Value then print the Value.
2. If node has child elements then print the set of Child Elements.
3. If node is Leaf Node print the Parent Node.

My XML File:-

```
     <document-metadata xmlns="http://breeze.macromedia.com/" version="1.0">
     <document-info>
         <title>Harry Potter</title>
         <summary/>
         <author/>
         <keywords/>
         <thumbnail href="data/thumb/thumb_slide_000001.jpg"/>
         <view-link href="/Viewer.swf?slide={position}"/>
     </document-info>
     <section xmlns="" type="slide" position="1">
         <title>Part 1</title>
         <content>XYZ</content>
         <related-content/>
         <thumbnail href="data/thumb/thumb_slide_000001.jpg"/>
     </section>
     <section xmlns="" type="slide" position="2">
         <title>Part 2</title>
         <content> PQRS</content>
         <related-content/>
         <thumbnail href="data/thumb/thumb_slide_000002.jpg"/>
     </section>
     </document-info>
     </document-metadata>
```

My C# Code:-

```
public string XmlNodeFind(string xmlUrl, string keyword)
{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(xmlUrl);
    try
    {
        XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName(keyword);
        string result = "";
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            result = OutputNode(node);
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return "No Node Exists";
    }
} 
public string OutputNode(XmlNode node)
{
    try
    {
        if (node.Value == null)
        {
            if (node.HasChildNodes)
            {
                XmlNodeList childern = node.ChildNodes;
                string str = "";
                foreach (XmlNode child in childern)
                    str = str + child.Name.ToString() + " <> ";
                //OutputNode(child);
            }
            else if (node.ParentNode != null)
            {
                return node.ParentNode.Name.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return node.Name.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return node.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return "Error Occured";
    }
    return node.Value.ToString();
}
```

The Problem with my code is that when I submit my URl of XML and Keyword through an aspx page the output is always "No Node Exists."

I read few posts ton extracting nodes based on Keywords and prior they were advises to check namespace. But my XML file is not the same always. The URL will change the XML file being used to check the node.

THIS IS FINAL CODE THAT I FIXED:-

```
public string XmlNodeFind(string xmlUrl, string keyword)
{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(xmlUrl);
    XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName(keyword);
    string result = "";
    XmlNode node = nodes[0];
    if (node != null)
    {
            result = OutputNode(node);
            return result;
    }
    else
      return "Node Does Not Exist !!! Try with a Valid Node.";
} 
public string OutputNode(XmlNode node)
{
    try
    {
        if (node.HasChildNodes && node.FirstChild.Name != "#text")
        {
            XmlNodeList childern = node.ChildNodes;
            string str = "Child Nodes are:-";
            foreach (XmlNode child in childern)
                str += "&lt;" + child.Name + "&gt;";
            return str;
        }
        else if ( node.OuterXml!=null && node.InnerText.ToString() != String.Empty) 
            return node.InnerText.ToString();
        else if (node.ParentNode != null)
            return node.ParentNode.Name;
        else
            return node.Name;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return "Error Occured : Try Again with New Input Set";
    }
```

}

Comment: What is your original exception ?

Comment: System.ServiceModel.FaultException

(The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults)

Comment: It may not be relevant but your XML file is not valid since the two top tags are not closed by matching tags (capitals vs. small letters).

Comment: My Apologies :- it is a typo error by me.

Comment: Are you sure you can access the url or file-location from your service ? Have you tried hard-coding your xml instead of loading it from a URI ?

Comment: Yes my Url is working and it is giving me list of node list too.
<code>
 XmlNodeList childern = node.ChildNodes;
                string str = "";
                foreach (XmlNode child in childern)
                    str = str + child.Name.ToString() + " <> ";
                //OutputNode(child);
</code>

In this code I missed to return the return str value.

After returning the value of str then to the output is wrong.

after returning the output is  "#text <>"

Comment: @tazyDevel : the GetElementByTagName is giving me a list of node I just want to select the node by this Xmlnode node = xdoc.GetElementByTagName(keyword)[0];

Comment: I have fixed majority of the problem in the code the only thing left in this is that the code is not returning the value of the node.

Comment: This is final code that I fixed:-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string XmlNodeFind(string xmlUrl, string keyword)
{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(xmlUrl);
    XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName(keyword);
    string result = "";
    XmlNode node = nodes[0];
    //result = node.LocalName + " - - " + node.Name + " - - " + node.NodeType + " - - " + node.OuterXml;
    //return result;    
    //foreach (XmlNode node in nodes){
    if (node != null)
    {
            result = OutputNode(node);
            return result;
    }
    else
      return "Node Does Not Exist !!! Try with a Valid Node.";
} 
public string OutputNode(XmlNode node)
{
    try
    {
        if (node.HasChildNodes && node.FirstChild.Name != "#text")
        {
            XmlNodeList childern = node.ChildNodes;
            string str = "Child Nodes are:-";
            foreach (XmlNode child in childern)
                str += "&lt;" + child.Name + "&gt;";
            return str;
        }
        else if ( node.OuterXml!=null && node.InnerText.ToString() != String.Empty) 
        {
            return node.InnerText.ToString();
        }
        /*else if (node.OuterXml != "" && node.Value != null)
        {
            string result;
            result = node.LocalName + " - - " + node.Name + " - - " + node.NodeType + " - - " + node.OuterXml;
            return result;
        }*/
        else if (node.ParentNode != null)
            return node.ParentNode.Name;
        else
            return node.Name;

        /*
        if (node.OuterXml != "")
        {
            if (node.HasChildNodes && node.FirstChild.Name != "#text")
            {
                XmlNodeList childern = node.ChildNodes;
                string str = "Child Nodes are:-";
                foreach (XmlNode child in childern)
                    str += "&lt;" + child.Name + "&gt;";
                return str;
            }
            else
            {
                if (node.OuterXml == string.Empty)
                    return node.ParentNode.Name;
                else
                    return node.OuterXml;
                //return "Outer Xml null part";
                //return node.OuterXml;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //return "Outer Xml null part";
            //string result;
            // = node.LocalName + " - - " + node.Name + " - - " + node.NodeType + " - - " + node.OuterXml;
            //return result;
            if (node.ParentNode != null)
            {
                string str = "Parent Node is :-";
                str += node.ParentNode.Name.ToString();
                return str;
            }
            else
                return node.Name;
            //return node.OuterXml;
        }
    */
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return "Error Occured : Try Again with New Input Set";
    }
}
```